# Unable to install wine on Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: apt, package-management, wine, dpkg, dependencies

I am trying to install wine on Ubuntu 20.10 using this command:

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

Yet it fails and shows the error below:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine-devel : Depends: wine-devel-i386 (= 6.2~groovy-1)
              Depends: wine-devel-amd64 (= 6.2~groovy-1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How may I fix this?

Comment: You haven't provided your OS & release details, however it looks like you've added 3rd party sources (PPAs etc) as I don't see those packages in Ubuntu repositories (nothing provided by Ubuntu sound require them either).  Have you added appropriate sources for your release?

Comment: I am assuming you are trying to install the latest release of wine 6 - this involves adding a 3rd party repository (as @guiverc also mentioned). Wine sometimes also requires enabling the installation of x86 architecture packages (when your OS is x64) using the command `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`. Have you done that? Have you double checked you've added the repository correctly?

Comment: [Wine's documentation](https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#How_do_I_solve_dependency_errors_when_trying_to_install_Wine.3F) regarding dependencies also might help.

Comment: I've added the x86 packages and added the repository. I am running ubuntu 20.04, I added repositories for 20.04 but 20.10 as well. would that be an issue? adding 20.10 repos? I don't know how to remove them if so.

Comment: Wine installs a staggering amount of packages - some official from Ubuntu's repositories (thus highly depending on your version), while also installing packages from the wine repository. Your installation command clearly shows it took the latest package version there is (which is also for Ubuntu 20.10) by default, causing missing or mismatching dependencies from Ubuntu, that lead to a dependency problem when installing wine packages.

Comment: Overall the best practice for a standard user is to install wine from the official Ubuntu repo (might not be the latest version), and it should work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest removing the 20.10 repos due to issues with apt. The way you would do so is doing editing the files in the `/etc/apt/sources.d` directory and removing the 20.10 repos from there. Then do `sudo apt update` and then do `sudo apt install wine` if you want to run x64 apps also do `sudo apt install wine64`.

Edit: This is not outdated. I use this method and it installs the latest version of wine which is wine 5.0

Comment: Those files end up in the /etc/apt/sources.d/ directory now, the .list is not edited anymore. Getting rid of the 20.10 sources is indeed the solution, you cannot mix the releases they need to match or it will never work. And for the amount of times I see this on here, for the wine in particular, you would think there should be HUGE warning this needs to match your install or do not do it, but apparently not.

Comment: This is completely wrong. Wine is never installed from standard Apt-Get repositories like that. It reverts back to Wine 1.6 (from years and years ago) Posted full answer below.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'm sorry that you have to deal with this. On Debian/Ubuntu systems, the Wine installation procedure detailed in their site is obsolete and causes a lot of problems.
I will detail for you the procedure to install any Wine version that you want without having to deal with external repositories, this is the MANUAL procedure.

Installing older/different versions of Wine than the latest ones from the repositories in Debian/Ubuntu system is a pain in the rear extremity.

Plan B: consider hopping over to Manjaro, if it's possible for you to do so. Why? Because the Manjaro version of the Wine package comes bundled IN A SINGLE PACKAGE, and you install it using A SINGLE COMMAND:

```
sudo pacman -U /local_path/wine-staging-5.1-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst
or, in the case you miss dependencies..
sudo pacman -Sy /path/wine...
(I think that's the command... I'm not in Manjaro right now,
the Sy command will download the dependencies for you 
WITHOUT performing a full system upgrade, only the packages you need...
pacman -U is the equivalent of sudo dpkg -i , for manual install)
```

OK. If hopping over to Arch/Manjaro is NOT a possibility for you, these below are the steps for MANUALLY installing older versions of Wine on Debian/Ubuntu-based distros:

1. Let's say you want to install Wine version 4.1 (one of the last versions of Wine before the Wineprefix size increased from 100 MB straight to 600 MB, without no additional benefits and no avoidance of the usual bugs from the last 10 years...)
   Go to https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/
   and download all packages that have 4.1 in their name (they should have the same Date to them)

In the case of Wine 4.1 (the version that I've found to be the optimal one) these are the packages you need. You always will need FIVE packages in total.

```
winehq-staging_4.1_buster_amd64.deb
wine-staging_4.1_buster_amd64.deb
wine-staging_4.1_buster_i386.deb
wine-staging-amd64_4.1_buster_amd64.deb
wine-staging-i386_4.1_buster_i386.deb
```

2. Installation order. Here comes the tricky part, after you do it the 1st time it should be easier the next times. First, you install the biggest i386 package, always. Then, you install the small i386 package. Then, install the big amd64 package, and the small amd64 package. The last to be installed should be winehq (which only comes in amd64 form)

Below is a copy of my bash history with the order of commands I used to do this in shortest time.

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo dpkg -i /path/wine-staging-i386_4.1_buster_i386.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg -i /path/wine-staging_4.1_buster_i386.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg -i /path/wine-staging-amd64_4.1_buster_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg -i /path/wine-staging_4.1_buster_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg -i /path/winehq-staging_4.1_buster_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get update
...
winecfg    <used to create the initial Wine prefix>
<use these ones below to reassure that you have all libs installed correctly>
...
WINEPREFIX=~/.wine32 WINEARCH=win32 winecfg  <to test if 32-bit is working OK>
WINEPREFIX=~/.wine64 WINEARCH=win64 winecfg  <to test if 64-bit is working OK>
<you should not see errors in the terminal of the type
"but the wrong architecture is being used" >
```

Notice how you need to run

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

every single time each package is installed. That will guarantee that the individual dependencies to each package are installed and configured, before you install the next package. (this is only needed the 1st time you do this... after that, you can put all these dependencies, store them in a Backup location, and install them all-at-once using sudo dpkg -i /path/*.deb )

3. Sometimes, and I don't understand why this happens, you won't be able to use Wine 64 bits, or you won't be able to use Wine 32 bits, one of the two. If that happens, simply re-install one of the big Wine packages again (depending if you need amd64 or i386)

   sudo dpkg -i /path/wine-staging-amd64_4.1_buster_amd64.deb

It's very unfortunate that Wine has been distributed like this on Debian/Ubuntu system, it's an overcomplicated process with a lot of time wasted. The way Manjaro does it should become the official way Wine is distributed from now on.